# Is RStudio editing scripts upon saving?

Tags: r, rstudio

I am reading pdf files with R. Before I analyze them, I perform a cleaning process.

More specifically, I am using this custom function:

```
cleanFile = function(x) {
    x = str_replace_all(string = x, pattern = "\\s+", replacement = " ") # not interesting for this post
    x = str_replace_all(string = x, pattern = "–", replacement = "-")
}
```

The second line is replacing a special character which my pdf files contain and looks just like a hyphen, with the "normal" hyphen character, `"-"`.

This is some code afterwards:

```
pdfClean = lapply(pdfList, cleanFile) # files cleansed
str_detect(pdfClean[[1]], "–") # checking if the special character appears - this last bit is not part of the script, I type it in the console so it's not affected by save.
```

When I save and run my script, the last line surprisingly returns `TRUE`.
I understand that the `"–"` character has been replaced with something different, because if I replace it back in my code and run the same script without saving, the last line returns `FALSE`, as expected.

Furthermore, this issue has only appeared now that I have changed my computer. In the past, I was using a different one and my code was running without any issue whatsoever.

I tried to experiment a bit with Tools --> Global Options --> Code --> Saving --> Default text encoding, but I didn't manage to fix anything.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The short answer is yes. RStudio replaces certain special characters, e.g. the soft hyphen, upon saving. It’s an annoying bug. You can work around it by using escape sequences instead of Unicode characters but of course this isn’t really acceptable behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Can you please explain how this special character should be escaped?

Comment: Also, how is it working fine in one computer and not in another one?

Comment: I’m surprised it works on some computers but I guess the bug is probably not straightforward. As for how to escape the characters, check out the “character constants” section on https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Quotes.html. You then need to look up the Unicode codepoint — here, U+2013. The result is `'\u2013'` (or, if you prefer, `'\u{2013}'`).